# Find word in a grid of characters

Tags: java, algorithm

I have to find how many times a given string can be built from a 2D grid of letters:

To build the word, I can start anywhere then move from cell to cell in one of 3 directions:

```
a) same row, next column (right)
b) next row, same column (down)
c) next row, next column (diagonal right and down)
```

Example:

```
char[][] grid = {{'a', 'a'}, {'a', 'a'}};

String str = "aa";

output:
5

Explanation:
a) [0,0][0,1]
b) [0,0][1,0]
c) [1,0][1,1]
d) [0,1][1,1]
e) [0,0][1,1]
```

This is my code so far:

```
class Solution {
    
    public boolean exist(char[][] grid, String str) {
        int m=grid.length,n=grid[0].length;
        boolean[][] visited=new boolean[m][n];
        int result = 0;
        for (int i=0;i< m;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<n;j++){               
                if (dfs(grid,visited,i,j,0,str)){
                    result++;
                }              
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    private boolean dfs(char[][] grid, boolean[][] visited, int x, int y, int i, String str){         
        int m=grid.length,n=grid[0].length;   
        if (i==str.length()) return true;
        
        if(x<0||x>=m||y<0||y>=n) return false;
        if(visited[x][y]) return false;
        if(grid[x][y]!=str.charAt(i)) return false;
        int[][] dirs={{1,0},{0,1},{1,1}};
        visited[x][y]=true;
        for (int[] dir: dirs){
            int x1=x+dir[0], y1=y+dir[1];
            if (dfs(grid, visited, x1, y1, i+1, str)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        visited[x][y]=false;
        return false;                                                                          
    }
}
```

For the sample input I mentioned above I am able to get result as 2 instead of 5.

How can I fix this?
Is there any other better approach?

Comment: Hint: when you dont understand what your code is doing, then A) learn how to use a debugger or B) simply add print statements. Start with a pen and a piece of paper. "Run" the code mentally, then compare what many many print statements tell you what happens. Turning to *other* people to explain your code to you of course works ... but takes away like 50% of the learning experience YOU need to make.

Comment: @GhostCatm, I tried that, the problem is in lines `if (dfs(grid, visited, x1, y1, i+1, str)){return true;}`, it is not checking the remaining cells to get correct count. When I tried to navigate other cells without returning, I am getting output as 15 instead of 5.

Comment: Hint: Start by deleting `visited`

Answer (score 0):

Start at 0,0 work across the columns and down the rows.
Create a method `boolean check(String word, int startRow, int startCol, int dRow, int dCol)`  it will return true if the word is found beginning at `startRow`,`startCol` incrementing the column by `dCol` and the row by `dRow` after finding each letter. It can return `false` immediately if the letter being checked doesn't match or if the row or column would be out of bounds.
Call it three times in the loop, first with `dRow = 0` and `dCol = 1`, then with both set to 1, then with `dRow = 1` and `dCol = 0`.

Name your methods better `dfs` is not a good name.

Here's my version, not exactly as described above.  I've decided to return an int rather than a boolean so I can easily add the result to the total.  I've hard-coded a grid of letters just to simplify the example.

```
public class FindWord {
    static char [][] grid = {
        {'b','a','d'},
        {'o','a','k'},
        {'d','a','d'}
    };
    static final int cols = grid[0].length;
    static final int rows = grid.length;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        countWords("bad");
        countWords("dad");
        countWords("oak");
        countWords("bod");
        countWords("bid");
        countWords("aaa");
        countWords("aa");
        countWords("d");
    }

    private static void countWords(String word) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                total += find(word,r,c,0,1) // across
                    + find(word,r,c,1,1) // diagonal
                    + find(word,r,c,1,0); // down
            }
        }
        System.out.println(total);
    }

    private static int find(String word, int row, int col, int dRow, int dCol) {
        for (char letter :  word.toCharArray()) {
            if (row >= rows || col >= cols || grid[row][col] != letter)
                return 0;
            row += dRow;
            col += dCol;
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

You might notice that this example has a bug for one letter words.  It counts one letter words 3 times because it considers the same starting position as across, diagonal, and down.  That is easy to fix with a condition to only check the "across" case and not the other two if the word length is one.  I'll leave it to you to make that adjustment.

Comment: dfs = depth first search, probably.